# Mysql2::Error: Column in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, activeadmin

I have 3 tables drivers, jobs and tip_travel_time. And their associations are like this

```
Class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :driver, primary_key: :username
end

Class Driver < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs, foreign_key: :driver_id, primary_key: :username
  has_many :tip_travel_times,foreign_key: :driver_id
end

class TipTravelTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :driver
end
```

Now I am using activeadmin and want to combine these two queries together

```
TipTravelTime.joins(:driver).where('users.runsheet_type IN (?,?,?)',Driver::LIQUID, Driver::FRONTLIFT, Driver::REARLIFT).group(:driver_id).select('ceil(avg(time_difference)/60) as average_time_in_minutes, driver_id').order(:driver_id)

Job.joins(:driver).where('users.runsheet_type IN (?,?,?)',Driver::LIQUID, Driver::FRONTLIFT, Driver::REARLIFT).group(:driver_id).where('completed_at is not null and started_at is not null').select('ceil(AVG(completed_at - arrived_at)/60) as average_completion_time_in_minutes, driver_id').order(:driver_id)
enter code here
```

And I am combining them by following Query:

```
Driver.joins(:tip_travel_times, :jobs).where('runsheet_type IN (?,?,?)',Driver::LIQUID, Driver::FRONTLIFT, Driver::REARLIFT).group(:driver_id).where('jobs.completed_at is not null and jobs.started_at is not null').select('ceil(AVG(jobs.completed_at - jobs.arrived_at)/60) as average_completion_time_in_minutes, ceil(avg(tip_travel_times.time_difference)/60) as average_time_in_minutes, jobs.driver_id').order(:driver_id)
```

But last query is returning me following error: 
`Mysql2::Error: Column 'driver_id' in field list is ambiguous: SELECT  COUNT(*) AS count_all, driver_id AS driver_id FROM users INNER JOIN tip_travel_times ON tip_travel_times.driver_id = users.id INNER JOIN jobs ON jobs.driver_id = users.username WHERE users.type IN ('Driver') AND (runsheet_type IN ('liquid','frontlift','rearlift')) AND (jobs.completed_at is not null and jobs.started_at is not null) GROUP BY driver_id LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 0` 
 Any idea where its going wrong or anything else I can do to achieve this?

Comment: You have `Job` and `TipTravelTime` which both have `driver_id` columns hence the ambiguousness

Comment: @j-dexx how can we avoid that and use table names in rails activerecord methods?

Comment: Looks like it might just be the order at the end, rails will default to order by the id of the driver because you're querying the driver so you might just be able to remove the order clause

Answer (score 1):

use `column name` with `table name` like `tip_travel_times.driver_id`

your query like that :-

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, 
tip_travel_times.driver_id AS driver_id 
FROM users.....
```

Comment: Any rails method to achieve similar query without using SQL?

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912040/ambiguous-column-in-mysql-rails-find-method @AdnanAli

Answer (score 1):

If two table have similar columns, then there will be an ambiguity problem in table joins.

Your query will be

```
TipTravelTime.joins(:driver).where('users.runsheet_type IN (?,?,?)',Driver::LIQUID, Driver::FRONTLIFT, Driver::REARLIFT).group("tip_travel_times.driver_id").select('ceil(avg(time_difference)/60) as average_time_in_minutes, tip_travel_times.driver_id').order("tip_travel_times.driver_id asc")

Job.joins(:driver).where('users.runsheet_type IN (?,?,?)',Driver::LIQUID, Driver::FRONTLIFT, Driver::REARLIFT).group("jobs.driver_id").where('completed_at is not null and started_at is not null').select('ceil(AVG(completed_at - arrived_at)/60) as average_completion_time_in_minutes, jobs.driver_id').order("jobs.driver_id asc")
```

If you want group by driver_id contained in jobs table then

```
Driver.joins(:tip_travel_times, :jobs).where('runsheet_type IN (?,?,?)',Driver::LIQUID, Driver::FRONTLIFT, Driver::REARLIFT).group("jobs.driver_id").where('jobs.completed_at is not null and jobs.started_at is not null').select('ceil(AVG(jobs.completed_at - jobs.arrived_at)/60) as average_completion_time_in_minutes, ceil(avg(tip_travel_times.time_difference)/60) as average_time_in_minutes, jobs.driver_id').order("jobs.driver_id asc")
```

If you want group by driver_id contained in tip_travel_times table then

```
Driver.joins(:tip_travel_times, :jobs).where('runsheet_type IN (?,?,?)',Driver::LIQUID, Driver::FRONTLIFT, Driver::REARLIFT).group("tip_travel_times.driver_id").where('jobs.completed_at is not null and jobs.started_at is not null').select('ceil(AVG(jobs.completed_at - jobs.arrived_at)/60) as average_completion_time_in_minutes, ceil(avg(tip_travel_times.time_difference)/60) as average_time_in_minutes, tip_travel_times.driver_id').order("tip_travel_times.driver_id asc")
```

instead of

```
TipTravelTime.joins(:driver).where('users.runsheet_type IN (?,?,?)',Driver::LIQUID, Driver::FRONTLIFT, Driver::REARLIFT).group(:driver_id).select('ceil(avg(time_difference)/60) as average_time_in_minutes, driver_id').order(:driver_id)

Job.joins(:driver).where('users.runsheet_type IN (?,?,?)',Driver::LIQUID, Driver::FRONTLIFT, Driver::REARLIFT).group(:driver_id).where('completed_at is not null and started_at is not null').select('ceil(AVG(completed_at - arrived_at)/60) as average_completion_time_in_minutes, driver_id').order(:driver_id)
```

Enjoy...

Comment: these two queries run fine problem is with third one which is combination of the two

Answer (score 0):

Try below, Let me know if this help you out? change `:drive_id` with '`table_name.drive_id`'

```
Driver.joins(:tip_travel_times, :jobs).where('runsheet_type IN (?,?,?)',Driver::LIQUID, Driver::FRONTLIFT, Driver::REARLIFT).group('table_name.driver_id').where('jobs.completed_at is not null and jobs.started_at is not null').select('ceil(AVG(jobs.completed_at - jobs.arrived_at)/60) as average_completion_time_in_minutes, ceil(avg(tip_travel_times.time_difference)/60) as average_time_in_minutes, jobs.driver_id').order('table_name.driver_id')
```